# What is the performance (Big-O) for removeAll() of a treeset?

Tags: big-o, treeset, removeall

I'm taking a Java data structures course atm. One of my assignment asks me to choose a data structure of my choice and write a spell checker program. I am in the process of checking the performance of the different data structures.

I went to the api for treeset and this is what it says...
"This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains)."

would that include removeAll()?

how else would I be able to figure this out

thank you in advance

Comment: If I were writing a spell-checker program, I would use a hash set to store the dictionary.That gives you constant time access to each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not include removeAll(), but I have to disagree with polkageist's answer. It is possible that removeAll() could be executed in constant time depending on the implementation, although it seems most likely that the execution would happen in linear time.

I think that NlogN would be if it was implemented in pretty much the worst way. If you are removing each element, there is no need to search for elements. Any element that you have needs to be removed, so there's no need to search.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. For an argument collection of size k, the worst-case upper bound of removeAll() is, of course, O(k*log n) - because *each* of the elements contained in the argument collection have to be removed from the tree set (this requires at least searching for them), each of this searches yielding a cost of log n.